# How to Create of list containing links using javascript

Tags: javascript

Am pretty new to JavaScript and trying to create a list containing links. so how do we achieve it using JavaScript? Assuming the contents that are part of the list are available as an array.

What needs to be acheived is

LinkList

- Link1
- Link2

Link1 and Link2 are links.

Statically in HTML page, it can be acheived as given below

```
<p>LinkList</p><ul>
 <li><a href="www.google.com">Link1</a></li>
 <li><a href="www.facebook.com">Link2</a></li></ul>
```

**if we get Link1 and Link2 as an array, how can the dynamic creation of list containing links be achieved using Javascript?**

Comment: And you have already tried...

Comment: If you post your best attempt, we can help you improve it.

Comment: i havent tried it.. :(

Comment: @DeepakP That's fine; go try now. :) If you edit your post to include your best attempt (and let me know by @-responding to me), I'd be happy to help you.

Comment: i just tried as below

 $.each(list, function(index, value) {    
  linkList.push($('<li/>').text(value.linkName));  
 });

Where linkList is a list which shall be given as an input for the UI component. 

This just creates a list but doenst create a link :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posted in your comment above is a good start. Rather than adding the link name as text, you need to create an anchor element and `append` it to your `li` element.

Try something like the following. It's more complicated than it has to be, but it also is probably more readable than some other solutions.

```
var Link = function(href, name) {
    this.href = href;
    this.name = name;
    this.generateAnchor = function() {
        return $("<a href='" + this.href + "'>" + this.name + "</a>");
    };
};


var links = [new Link("http://www.google.com", "Google"),
             new Link("http://www.yahoo.com", "Yahoo")];


for (var i = 0; i<links.length; i++) {
    var listElement = $("<li></li>").append(links[i].generateAnchor());
    $("ul.linkList").append(listElement);
}
```

Working example in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/Nt53t/1/).

If you have any questions, let me know.  For next time, please remember that StackOverflow is intended to help refine existing code and answer questions that are the fruit of research.  The more of your work and research you show, the more helpful we can be.